# Update on a linked table '???' failed

Tags: sql, vb6

I am recieving a error 'Run-time error 3157: ODBC--update on a linked table ''???' failed.' when i try to update a table through VB6 code but updating works normal through MS Access.

I am using a MS Access as frontend for SQL 2008.

Table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE [varijable] (
    [rabat_racuni] FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
    [rabat_diskont] FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
    [napomena_racuni] NTEXT,
    [napomena_predracuni] NTEXT,
    [napomena_diskont] NTEXT,
    [napomena_revers] NTEXT,
    [putanja_artikli] NVARCHAR(225),
    [rab] FLOAT DEFAULT 0,
    [prodaja] INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    [profaktura] INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    [faktura] INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    [revers] INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    [dan_azur] DATETIME,
    [status] SMALLINT,
    [oznaka_goriva] NVARCHAR(50),
    [naknada_goriva] FLOAT,
    [sifra_naknade] NVARCHAR(255),
    [server_baza] NTEXT,
    [an] [INTEGER] IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [varijable$an] PRIMARY KEY ([an])
);
GO
```

Code with update:

```
 'odredi broj
 Data28.RecordSource = "select * from varijable"
 Data28.Refresh
  'ispravi brojeve u datoteci rednih brojeva
Data28.Recordset.Edit
If Combo4.ListIndex = 0 Then
 br = Data28.Recordset.Fields("prodaja") + 1
Data28.Recordset.Fields("prodaja") = br
End If
If Combo4.ListIndex = 1 Then
br = Data28.Recordset.Fields("profaktura") + 1
Data28.Recordset.Fields("profaktura") = br
End If
If Combo4.ListIndex = 2 Then
br = Data28.Recordset.Fields("faktura") + 1
Data28.Recordset.Fields("faktura") = br
End If
If Combo4.ListIndex = 3 Then
 br = Data28.Recordset.Fields("revers") + 1
Data28.Recordset.Fields("revers") = br
End If
''on error GoTo greska
Data28.Recordset.Update <----- Throws error 3157
```

And why does VB6 give me error without table name, instead it gives '???'

Answer (score 1):

3157 is usually caused by a rule violation.
That could mean:

1. The ODBC database is read-only, or the account associated to the ODBC connection does not have permission to update data in that database.
2. The ODBC connection failed (connection string is wrong)

I'd start with checking if the connection is working for any queries if it is, are any create statements working via VB?

Comment: I am using same connection string and same account for updating, selecting, and deleting on all of my tables in same database, for 15 out of 35 tables everything is working (all statements)

Comment: for 20/35 you receive this error? Are they all in the same schema?

Also what update are you trying to perform? (Does it hit any of the constraints?)

Comment: I have updated my question with code and table structure @SmileTechie

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same issue for several days. In my case, it turned out that I was updating records in SQL Workbench in Oracle and my Access Application that works with the same data was getting the 3157 ODBC Update Error.

The root cause turned out to be that when I update the records in SQL Workbench, I need to issue a 'commit' statement to make the changes permanent. Until then, those records are in a locked state and any other application trying to alter them will get the 3157 Error.

Hope this helps somebody.